# Import Umbraco property editor

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We have site where a user went to the Data Types, saw we had a Content Picker data type using "(Obsolete) Content Picker" (`Umbraco.ContentPickerAlias`) and changed it to `Umbraco.ContentPicker2`

Our code relies on the obsolete one currently and now he cannot set the content we want him to.

Is there a way to recreate/reimport the Obsolete property editor into Umbraco?

Answer (score 1):

On the Data Types node you can click on the ... and create a 'New data type' - then select the obsolete one to create it again.

But in theory, I believe you could just do the opposite of what the user did, on the ContentPicker click edit and pick the property editor from the dropdown if available?

Comment: that is my exact problem - the obsolete one does not appear in the dropdown list when I create a new data type. I did find a setting that control this though and have posted an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Within the `umbracoSettings.config` file, there is a property you can create/set to true that will make obsolete data types become available to use against data types

```
<showDeprecatedPropertyEditors>true</showDeprecatedPropertyEditors>
```